# How to list a user's GitHub repository via the GitHub API

Tags: php, github, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm trying to list the private repositories of a user via the GitHub API. The request I'm currently making to GitHub is the following.

```
https://api.github.com/users/username/repos?sort=updated&direction=desc&visibility=all
```

It does return the user's repositories but not the private ones. At first I thought that the problem was with the scopes options on my OAuth token. I currently have the following set in my application.

```
'user',
'repo',
'repo_deployment',
'admin:repo_hook',
'admin:org_hook',
```

But even if I set all of the scope option on my dev box, I see all the public repositories but none of the user's private ones. I've also tried removing all of the parameters from the url. So that the request is the following.

```
https://api.github.com/users/username/repos
```

Which again did not return the user's private repositories.

I am trying to get the private repositories for the current user. But only the ones owned under their account.

Comment: > user's private ones.  Just to be clear you mean your private repositories or the private repositories of the user that the token belongs to correct?

Comment: So, getting the private repositories of the current OAuth user. Not necessarily the private repositories of another user. If I understand you currently.

Comment: Posted an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106135/1174076

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong endpoint for this. You are after the following endpoint instead:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories

```
https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

> List repositories that the authenticated user has explicit permission (:read, :write, or :admin) to access. The authenticated user has explicit permission to access repositories they own, repositories where they are a collaborator, and repositories that they can access through an organization membership.

I've just tested it and this returns your private repositories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to [authorize](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) yourself for permission of listing your private repositories.

Get an OAuth Token [from the account](https://github.com/settings/tokens) (or from the [OAuth Authorizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/)), then add the token as a GET parameter (in query string `?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN`) or a HTTP header (`Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN`) of your request, you may have permission for your need.

Comment: he is using the wrong endpoint for this call, see my answer below or above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106135/1174076

Comment: Then I found https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/968#issuecomment-453755909.

Comment: @bitoiu Yes, you're. I was using the wrong endpoint to get the to try and get the data.

Comment: @JamesHudson Remember to accept his answer if your question is solved :-)

Comment: @JamesHudson I think you should accept the other answer instead, his answer is more suitable than mine ;-)

Comment: @JamesHudson not to be particular but you accepted the wrong answer, thank you GenoChen for the kindness :bow:

Comment: @bitoiu Sorry just changed it. It's too early in the morning!